# is the approach shown below in $\lim_{n \to \infty} [\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} ]=1$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The approach in a reference textbook:

Let $f_{n}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^{2}+n}}$ Then $\lim_{n \to \infty } f_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}=1$

From Cauchy's first theorem on limits:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f_{1}+f_{2}+\cdots+f_{n}}{n}=1
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}[\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} ]=1\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} [\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} ]=1\\
\end{align*}

Is this approach correct as $f_{1}$ is taken as $\frac{n}{\sqrt{1+n^{2}}}$ instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or am I missing any aspect in applying the Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: This doesn't look correct.  I think it would be better if you show that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}=\frac{1}{n}-\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{k}{n^3}\right).$$  Therefore, the sum is $1-\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac1n\right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the sum be $S$.
$$\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}< S < \dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} \\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\le \lim_{n\to\infty}S \le \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} \\ 1 \le \lim_{n\to\infty}S\le 1 \\ \lim_{n\to\infty}S=1$$

Comment: thank you, I got this earlier but I am just looking at the correctness of that given approach.

Comment: Thats way easier that my version, GJ

Answer (score 1):

Correct approach: $$n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}<n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}.$$
Since there are limits $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}=1$$ then there is limit $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} \right)=1.$$

The approach in a reference textbook is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ n $ be a positive integer, we have the following :

\begin{aligned} 1-\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+k}}}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+k}}\right)}\\ &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{\sqrt{n^{2}+k}-n}{\sqrt{n^{2}+k}}}\\ &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^{2}+k}\left(\sqrt{n^{2}+k}+n\right)}}\\ &\leq\frac{1}{2n}\times\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\times\int_{0}^{1}{x\,\mathrm{d}x}=0\end{aligned}

In the fourth line we used that $ k\geq 0 $, and thus : $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+k}}}}=1 $$

Comment: You don't need that final limit. You can even use the crude estimate $\sum_{k=1}^n (k/n) \le \sum_{k=1}^n 1 = n$.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the thing you should understand to solve this is the result basically comes from the idea that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + i}}$$ is close to $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}$$
when $i \leq n$ and $n$ is big (and n times this is 1)

Now you need to quantitatively express that. First 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + i}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}} $$

The other way is a bit harder 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + i}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + (i/n^2)}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}( 1 - \frac{i}{2  n^2}))  $$ (the inequality  comes from convexity of the inverse square root)

then just sum those inequalities and you should find the limit